# Regex for abc followed by def followed by ghi and also individual words

Tags: java, regex

I want to have a regex such that I would like to have

abc followed by def followed by ghi and any spaces can be in between.

accept: abcdefghi, abc def ghi , individual abc, def,ghi as well.

How can I achieve in regex java.

I used `((abc)?[\s,،]*(def)?[\s,،]*(ghi\s*\d+)?(jkl\s*\d{9})?)`

This gives the result but for negative test like :

zksdfhhoiopokpjhhddfddfdfd

gives me matches for spaces.

Results
.matches() method: false
.lookingAt() method: true
Showing 6 matches
 k l m n o  in 
https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html

Comment: Do you mean like sequential optional parts? `abc(?:\s*def(?:\s*ghi(?:\s*jkl)?)?)?` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/s5Cynu/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be looking for a nested grouping structure with optional parts or an alternation which lists the individual parts.

Use a negative lookahead with a backreference to check what follows is not what is captured in group 1. The setup for the regex might be:

```
(abc(?:[\h,]*def(?:[\h,]*ghi)?)?|(?:abc|def|ghi))(?!\h+\1\b)
```

This will first match abc followed by an optional non capturing group `(?:...)?` which itself also contains an optional non capturing group. If that does not match, the alternation `|` checks for the individual matches.

Note that `\s` also matches a newline. I have used `\h` instead to match a horizontal whitespace character.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YLeKbj/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/MWGW8R)

Comment: This doesn't match individual def, ghi.

Comment: @LaxmiKadariya Do you mean like https://regex101.com/r/dWWzl1/1

Comment: This looks fine.

Comment: @LaxmiKadariya I have updated my answer.